# Python passing parameters with os.system on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, os.system

I've developed a python script on a Windows machine where at a point it calls another python script with some aruguments aswell.

## script.py

```
value="bar"
id="foo"
os.system('"Main.py" %s %s' % (eqid, value))
```

## main.py

```
 name=sys.argv[1]
 send=sys.argv[2]
```

This code works perfectly on Windows, and now im trying to run it on a Linux (Ubuntu) and im getting an error 
`sh 1: Main.py: not found` 

script.py and main.py are in the same directory asswell
What is wrong here? :/

Comment: Why aren't you *import*-ing the other script to execute its code as it is meant to be executed?

Comment: I notice that you have specified the script name as `main.py` but are calling `Main.py`. As well as the other suggestions, linux is case-sensitive so you should double check the case of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Linux how to run Main.py i.e. specify `'python "Main.py"'` (this isn't needed on Windows if python is set as the default program to use to open .py files, but it should still work fine to specify it on Windows regardless)

e.g.

```
~ $ cat Main.py
import sys
name=sys.argv[1]
send=sys.argv[2]
print name+" "+send
~ $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> value="bar";id="foo"
>>> os.system('python "Main.py" %s %s' % (id, value))
foo bar
0
```

But most likely you shouldn't be running a second python script like this, but should instead be importing it and calling it's code directly.

Answer (score 1):

linux probably doesn't have current dir in it's default path (security issue in case someone codes a malicious `ls` which is executed when you try to know what's in the directory).

So if the .py has the proper shebang you can do:

```
os.system('"./Main.py" %s %s' % (eqid, value))
```

but:

- consider importing the script instead of running a subprocess (which is debatable, for instance if you want to preserve both processes independence)
- `os.system` is now deprecated. A better approach would be using `subprocess` module.

Like this:

```
subprocess.call(["./Main.py",str(eqid), str(value)])
```

(note that to be stricly equivalent, I "converted" the arguments to strings, just in case they are, for instance, integers. That doesn't hurt)